# Rails .reject Turns Type ActiveRecord::Relation into Type Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to use the `.reject` method in Rails to remove the `current_user` from a search.  I do this as follows:

```
@users = User.where{(firstname =~ my{"%#{params[:term]}%"}) | (lastname =~ my{"%#{params[:term]}%"}) | (email =~ my{"%#{params[:term]}%"})}.select("id,firstname, lastname")
@users = @users.reject{|u| User.find(u.id) == current_user}
```

After the first line, if I call `@users.class`, I get `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but after using the `.reject` method, if I call `@users.class` I get `Array`.

How can I maintain an `ActiveRecord::Relation` after using the `.reject` method? I need an `ActiveRecord::Relation` in order to use the `.paginate` method in my next line, which is:

```
@user = @users.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:page_limit])
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use always `ActiveRecord` [api query methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database) to get an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (`reject` isn't). For example, combine `where`:

```
@users = User.where(your_first_conditions).
              where("id != :id", id: current_user.id).
              select([:id, :firstname, :lastname])
```

Comment: Thank you, works well! Quick quest - why do you use the last `select([:id, :firstname, :lastname])` statement? It seems to me that it should work with only the second `where("id != :id", id: current_user.id)` statement.

Comment: Yes, I added it because you have that statement in your question, but it works without it.

Comment: Ah yes, of course (being tired made me overlook that fact!) Thanks for the help!